# Rails: I want Server Sent Events. Do I have to drop Phusion Passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, server-sent-events

We currently have a rails 3 app (in the process of upgrading to rails 4) and I want to start using the ActionController::Live to play with Server Sent Events for some real time updates to our users.

My question is does this new functionality work with Phusion Passenger out of the box? Everything I read is using puma, rainbows or thin. I love how easy Passenger is for our deployment, I'd even be tempted to buy the enterprise version but not if it's going to require me configuring everything to get this working. If I have to configure everything I might as well go with an open source option.

Comment: you don't seem like you tried yet have you ?

Comment: No because we haven't updated to rails 4 yet. I'll give it a quick go on development. I also was curious if each connection would eat up a rails instance or if each instance could handle multiple connections?

Comment: That would depend on the concurrency settings. See http://blog.phusion.nl/2013/03/12/tuning-phusion-passengers-concurrency-settings/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Server Side Events works great on Phusion Passenger. I wrote a demo for you. Check out https://github.com/phusion/passenger-ruby-server-side-events-demo

Hongli Lai,
Phusion CTO
Phusion Passenger developer

Comment: Perfect. Keep up the good work Hongli. And thanks for running around on here answering questions!

Comment: This demo specifies directives that are only available in Enterprise.   Are there any recommendations for the open source version?

Comment: The Enterprise directives only provide concurrency optimizations. The demo works fine even without them.

Comment: It seems that it keeps a thread running for every connection, is there a chance to use EventMachine or something similar for that?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to post a Rails 4 solution i got to work seamlessly using passenger and redis..

i use ajax to response to publish events from redis you can just send data payload.

Do ensure is you rails enviornment file development.rb/production.rb

```
  config.cache_classes = true

  config.eager_load = true
```

You don't need puma, unicorn, goliath for SSE to work passenger serves fine.

[Solution here](http://www.abhijat.name/2014/06/actioncontrollerlive-rails-4-nginx.html)